# Why are molecular reactions endo- or exo-thermic?

Tags: energy, heat

It seems strange to me that chemical reactions should be exothermic, meaning the molecules move faster after the reaction.

Normally, in physics when two moving objects collide and stick together, the resultant velocity of the combined object is *less* than that of the constituent objects, due to conservation of momentum.

Yet, when some molecules combine they move faster. An extreme example of this are fast reactions like explosives in which the chemicals combine and move off at high speeds, sometimes greater than the speed of sound (a "detonation").

Why would this be? Is there a theory that positively can predict this behavior? In other words, if I were to supply you the names of two chemical species of which you had no prior knowledge, could you predict ahead of time whether their reaction would be exothermic or not, and by how much? Or, can this only be determined experimentally?

Comment: Please refer to the spontaneous crystallization of a super saturated solution of sodium acetate.  This is a single example which invalidates your statement, so clearly we need to adjust your view on exothermic.  Although I'm not quite sure how.  Your view of what makes something exothermic is a likely consequence of a reaction being exothermic, not a rigorous requirement.

Comment: The short answer is that the energy change is the result of making and breaking chemical bonds not the collisions between molecules.

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking it in a pseudo classical way. In those terms, imagine bonds like some kind of springs with some potential energy. During the reaction there can be rupture or formation of springs, changing the potential energy. In consequence, due to energy conservation kinetic energy must change.

A pictorial argument, that may help comparing your view point about collisions and the chemical reaction case, that is not always true, can be go like this: If we think of two balls bonded by an ordinary spring, in the "relaxed" position (that occurs somewhere between max and min elongation) we have the minimum potential energy. This is also true for a diatomic molecule (look some graph of potential energy curve for a diatomic molecule). Imagine that two of this balls bonded by the spring collide in the region of the (ideal, non mass, non perturbed by the collision etc.) spring and cut them out:

[image]

If you make this collision the speed of each ball will remain the same due to the spring is mass less. If molecules were like the balls no change in temperature would occurs, because kinetic energy does not change.

The key point is that molecules does not behave like that, spring never cut so: potential energy always is present. So if they where molecules, as products the separation between balls is larger and so the potential energy is greater and the kinetic energy turns to be smaller.

Now, think in the backward reaction, this reaction would be an exothermic reaction.

I am not sure if that is the kind of answer you need. If not or if something is unclear leave a comment.

**Edit**
I forgot answer that last questions. Yes, the temperature change can be calculated. Normally what is calculated is the enthalpy change, but they can be related trough heat capacity. Of course there are limitations in precision and size of the molecule, but in essence the answer is *yes*, it can be calculated following the quantum mechanics principles.

Answer (score 2):

First, your question. Needless to say, you are right in your physics, but let me just restate. If two "objects" collide and combine, the law of momentum conservation does indeed dictate that the velocity of the conglomerate will be lower than the velocities of each of the starting objects.

*However, what objects are we speaking of?* The basic principles of mechanics, like above, all assume that the "object" is simply some ideal perfectly spherical substance that exhibits no properties that require further consideration. **Molecules and atoms, however, do not behave like macroscopic particles** such as beach balls or lumps of clay.

In classical physics (and physical chemistry), there is kinetic energy and potential energy (*gravitational*, *electrical*, *elastic*...). In chemistry, there is at least one more consideration--***chemical* potential energy**. Take the collision of two atoms to make a molecule, for instance. *What holds the two atoms together to make that molecule?* It is because **a bond formed** between the two atoms when they collided in the right manner. They end up sharing an electron, thus **releasing chemical potential energy** as they formed a (covalent) bond. *Chemical potential energy changes when bonds break or form.* *Formation of stronger bonds is exothermic, and destruction of stronger bonds (to form weaker bonds) is endothermic.* That molecule that formed has less chemical potential energy than the sum of the two atoms before. This is an exothermic reaction, because energy was released to form the bond (otherwise, why would it the molecule be more stable, given that entropy is already against its formation?). As a summary so far, considering only postulates of physics when dealing with atoms and molecule fails the same way that classical physics could not explain what became the domain of quantum physics.

OK, so that was a exothermic reaction. Explosive reactions are too, such as the decomposition of nitroglycerine. When this happens,
$\ce{4 C_3H_5N_3O_9 -> 6 N_2 + 12 CO_2 + 10H_2O + O_2}$, a lot of chemical potential energy as released because the products have stronger bonds.
The reaction is exothermic. What does that mean? Some energy has been introduced as thermal energy. Suppose that you had 20 atoms in a container. Two of them combine to make a molecule, releasing energy. That exothermic reaction means that chemical potential energy has decreased. By the conservation of energy, thermal energy (kinetic energy of individual particles) will increase. True, for a very short time after the formation of the molecule, that newly formed molecule will hold that extra energy. However, **the ensuing collisions with the other particles in the container means that the liberated energy is shared with all of its buddies**, and the kinetic energy of all of the particles increases, including the newly formed molecule.

To summarize, you need to aknowledge chemical potential energy. Perhaps also reread enthalpy with that in perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to answer your points directly I try to explain why reactions can be exothermic or endothermic. 
Chemical reactions depend on the different amount of chemical potential (energy) molecules have bound up in their chemical bonds.  
 Suppose, as a thought experiment, that we could take the atoms that will form a molecule and separate then by some huge distance, and we will call the energy they have, zero, (we can assume that they are stationary). Next we bring them together to form the molecule, in doing so the electrons in the atoms interact and release energy as chemical bonds are formed. Finally the molecule will have some total negative energy $\Delta H_1$, this is called the heat of formation and the subscript indicates its our first molecule.  (In chemistry negative energy denotes stability). 
We can repeat this process with all sorts of atoms to form any types of molecules we want, each time we obtain a heat of formation, $\Delta H_2$,$\Delta H_3$,$\Delta H_4$  etc, but these heats are not all the same, some large, some small. The reason is that not all types of chemical bonds have the energy,(C-O is different from C-C etc.) and not all types of molecules have the same number of bonds thus not all types of molecules have the same heat of formation.

The important point is that different types of molecules have different amounts of internal energy bound up in their bonds. This is released when a reaction occurs and redistributed in making the chemical bonds in product molecules. Sometimes more energy is available from the reactants than is needed to form products and so this is released as heat into the solution or gas depending on how the reaction is carried out. Sometimes its the other way round. 
Finally, the rates of reactions (how quickly they react) depend on the size of the potential energy barrier that exists between starting (reactants) and ending(product) molecules. The barrier is called the activation energy. If there were no barrier, all molecules would react immediately on contact and we, or any other living thing, would not exist).